# How to check if the entry widget is empty, if it only takes int values

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am creating a GUI with tkinter for my Password Generator App, in which I included is entry widget in which the users can enter the length of the password to be generated.

If the user does not enter any value(only integer) in the entry box I want to raise an error with *messagebox.showerror*. How can i check whether the entry box is empty or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

- You will need to `get` the value inside the `Entry` and store it into a variable.
- Then check the variable's length(using `len`) and put a condition that `if` its length is 0, That means the `Entry` is empty, then you can display an error message.
- After you have checked its length, you can now convert it into an integer.

Like in this **Example:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


def check():
    var = e.get()
    if len(var) == 0:
        messagebox.showerror('Error', 'Entry is empty')
    else:
        pass

    var = int(var)


root = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()

b = tk.Button(root, text='check', command=check)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I did the same with my code but it did'nt worked out for me. As in my question I specified that the value which we are entering the entry box is Interger not String. In your code you took the value as string not as a an integer. How can I deal with this problem if the value entered in the entry box is a integer. Example :[ var = int(e.get()) ]. If this is the situation how can I deal with it ? Well otherwise thanks for answering my question..

Comment: You can still do `len(e.get())`.  int("") raises an exception so you'll need to check the length before doing the int conversion.

Comment: @ShivanshMishra Sorry I didn't describe that part, You need to perform the length check before converting the string into an integer because it doesn't work on integer. Now I've updated the answer Please make sure to accept the answer if it works for you. :)

Comment: @ShivanshMishra Upvotes increase your reputation while downvotes decrease them. The reason for downvotes could be anything. A question might get downvoted if the answer could be found only with a little research, or if it is already asked by someone, and due to many other reasons. I think the reason for your question to be downvoted is that you didn't attach any piece of code with it. Next time try to attach a minimal example of your code like the example I have given you in the answer, as it clarifies the issue. :)

Comment: @DaniyalAhmad Thanks, I will keep that in mind in future!